# What is legacyNullReferencePolicy?

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, unmanaged

We are getting mysterious SEHExceptions in our C# application which may be coming from some unmanaged code (FFMPEG). Its not being caught by the try-catch blocks - so we are not certain what is causing it, but it is perhaps due to a null reference.

I found this on MSDN ([SEHException MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) which says:

> The .NET Framework often encounters unmanaged SEH exceptions that are automatically mapped to managed equivalents. There are two common unmanaged SEH exceptions:
>   STATUS_NO_MEMORY exceptions are automatically mapped to the OutOfMemoryException class.
>   STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION exceptions are automatically mapped as follows:
>
> If **legacyNullReferencePolicy** is applied, all access violations are mapped to the NullReferenceException class.

Now, this bit sounds interesting - if we could set this **legacyNullReferencePolicy** maybe these mysterious NullReferenceExceptions could be caught and we could find out where they are coming from.

But I can't find any information online about **legacyNullReferencePolicy**. What is it? Where do I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that *legacyNullReferencePolicy* is renamed in the final bits of .Net 4.0

You are looking for the [legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) setting in the `<runtime>` config section like so:

```xml
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

or decorate your method that needs to handle those state corruption exceptions with this attribute:[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

This example is taken from [this msdn article in the CLR Inside Out series of author Andrew Pardoe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx)

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] 
[SecurityCritical]
public static int Main() 
{ 
   try
     {
       // Catch any exceptions leaking out of the program 
     }
   catch (Exception e) 
       // We could be catching anything here 
     {

        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
        return 1; 
     } 

   return 0; 

}
```